go_router onExit, how to make example from docs null safe
I want to implement a dialog exactly as provided in the example in the docs from go_router:
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: <GoRoute>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      onExit: (BuildContext context) => showDialog<bool>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Do you want to exit this page?'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
                ),
                child: const Text('Go Back'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
                ),
                child: const Text('Confirm'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
);

When I copy & paste the example code, I get the following error displayed in vscode:
The return type 'Future<bool?>' isn't a 'FutureOr<bool>', as required by the closure's context.dart return_of_invalid_type_from_closure. I assume that is example is not yet updated for null safety.
Unfortunately, I am not suffiently experience with Flutter yet to make this example null safe.
Any idea how to make this example work?
Thanks for your help!

try waiting the response of the showDialog:
var response = await showDialog<bool>(...

and then  you can return the response
return response ?? false;

full code:
onExit: (BuildContext context) async {
          var response = await showDialog<bool>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Do you want to exit this page?'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
                    ),
                    child: const Text('Go Back'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                    },
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
                    ),
                    child: const Text('Confirm'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
          return response ?? false;
        },

